# codeigniter: access config variables from other config files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, configuration-files

I have two config files.

config.php (code igniters core config)

and email.php (autoloaded by the email class when it is used)

What i am wanting to do is.

In config.php have

`$config['env'] = 'hailwood_dev';`

then in email.php have

```
if($config['env'] == 'hailwood_dev'){
//email variables like smtp server to do with localhost
} elseif($config['env'] == 'production'){
//email variables like smtp server to do with production
}
```

But this is not having any effect (im guessing as $config['env'] does not have those values).

How can I access this value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked and at that point in the request lifecycle the config property of the CodeIgniter object is just an array, not a config object.

So you should be able to get at your configuration setting like this :

```
$this->config['env']
```

So this should work :

```
if ($this->config['env'] == 'hailwood_dev')
{
    //email variables like smtp server to do with localhost
} 
elseif ($this->config['env'] == 'production'){
    //email variables like smtp server to do with production
}
```

If you are autoloading configuration files, make sure they are autoloaded in the correct order.  A configuration file must be autoloaded after any it depends on.

Comment: In CI 3.17 `$config_component->config['your_config_item']` works for me

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your email config file.

```
$environment = config_item('env');
OR THIS
$environment = $this->config->item('env');
```

Not sure if the first will work on your setup.  Most people seem to use the second.

Comment: get told config is not an object

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $env = $this->config->item('env');

 if ($env == "dev_server")  {
   // Do this...
 }
 else  {
   // Do this..
 }
```

Comment: get told config is not an object

Comment: This one worked for me, accepted answer doesnt seem to work on the latest version of CodeIgnitor

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would want to put configuration in

- application/config/ceveloppment/my_config.php
- application/config/production/my_config.php

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Combining with other awnsers you could share information between two configuration files for the same environnement

Comment: by the way op has an epic avatar

Comment: Yeah, when first posting this question it was pre 2.0 so environments did not exist! And thanks, I quite like my avatar lol

Answer (score 0):

use config_item function (system/core/Common.php)

/**
* Returns the specified config item
*
* @access   public
* @return   mixed

Answer (score 0):

Please see below solutions

$this->config->config['base_url']

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->config);
```

Above will print required details

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter 3.0 the solution to accessing config variables in another config file is to get the CodeIgniter instance. Once you have a reference to it you can then access using the `item` function.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$var = $CI->config->item('item_name');
```

Comment: using hooks, this one has your app custom config settings stored in a mysql table: arjunphp.com/save-codeigniter-config-data-in-mysql-database/